# Problems with kde plasma dependencies

Tags: 15.04, uninstall, kde, dependencies

I wanted to try kde but when I installed it I got a few errors. I didn't think much of these and loaded up kde, and all I had was a cursor and a black screen. So I try'ed to uninstall it and it threw up this error.

```
eelis@eelis-All-Series:~$ sudo apt-get purge plasma-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-config-touchpad : Depends: plasma-desktop but it is not going to be installed
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I run `sudo apt-get -f install` and I get this error.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Dpkg tells me kde is not installed but apt tells me it is.

It would be great if any of you could give some insight into my problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I managed to solve my issue.

I ran:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and worked fine.